# Not able to open notepad in AutoIt with Java

Tags: java, autoit

Here I am trying to open the notepad in AutoIt with Java. However I am unable to open it with the following code.

```
public class Notepad {
    public static String jvmBitVersion() { //returning the JVM Version
        return System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        String jacobDllVersionToUse;
        System.out.println("JVM version is: " +jvmBitVersion());

        if (jvmBitVersion().contains("32")) {   //Checking for the JVM Version
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-M2-x86.dll"; // If the version is 32- bit use this.
        }
        else { // enter code here
            jacobDllVersionToUse = "jacob-1.18-M2-x64.dll"; // if the version is 64-bit go for this
        }

        File file = new File("lib", jacobDllVersionToUse); // file location for jacob
        System.setProperty(LibraryLoader.JACOB_DLL_PATH, file.getAbsolutePath());

        AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
        x.run("notepad.exe"); // trying to open the notepad

        x.winActivate("Untitled - Notepad"); // waiting for the notepad to open
        x.winWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad");

        x.send("This is some text"); // Once the notepad is open write into it.

    }
}
```

If in place of notepad.exe I am giving calc.exe it is working fine. If I am opening the notepad manually after running this is code it is writing to the notepad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting notepad as immediately `shown` will solve this problem.

**Notepad**

```
AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
x.run("notepad.exe", "", AutoItX.SW_SHOW);
x.winActivate("Untitled - Notepad");
x.winWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad");
x.send("This is some text");
```

**[Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/)**

```
AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
x.run("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe");
x.winActivate("[CLASS:Notepad++]");
x.winWaitActive("[CLASS:Notepad++]");
x.send("This is some text");
```

Comment: @AnubhavMishra I updated my answer with an example for Notepad++.

Answer (score 1):

Try the full path:

```
x.run("C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe")
```

And i would use a different order for your wait commands, because you can't activate a window that "doesn't" exist and it would be smarter to activate a window before you use send() commands. The correct order would be:

```
x.winWaitActive("Untitled - Notepad");

x.winActivate("Untitled - Notepad");
x.send("This is some text");
```

You could also use only WinWait()

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
AutoItX x = new AutoItX();
x.run("notepad.exe", "C:/Windows/System32/", AutoItX.SW_SHOW); // trying to open the notepad

x.winActivate("Sin título: Bloc de notas"); // waiting for the notepad to open
x.winWaitActive("Sin título: Bloc de notas");
x.send("This is some text"); // Once the notepad is open write into it.
```

Notice that title of window must match with Windows application. In my case, Windows is in Spanish and title is "Sin título: Bloc de notas".